# Sending acknowledgements with socket.io, says my function is undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, socket.io

I am trying to use acknowledgements with socket.io as defined in http://socket.io/#how-to-use "Sending and getting data (acknowledgements)".

My client code looks like

```
sio.emit('ferret', 'tobi', function (data) {
  console.log(data);
});
```

And my server code is:

```
socket.on('ferret', function (name, fn) {
  fn('woot');
});
```

But I'm getting an error that's crashing my node server:

```
fn('woot');
23:13:48 web.1  |         ^
23:13:48 web.1  | TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

Which I find strange because if I add:

```
console.log(name);
console.log(fn);
```

, name will log Tobi, but for what ever reason fn is logging undefined.

Any information would be awesome!!

Comment: It works for me. Can you post complete code?

Comment: Code it correct. Maybe you need to restart node.js app?

Comment: I'm facing this problem too. Did you ever solve it?

Comment: If anyone is facing this problem what solved it for me is making sure that on the client, the `emit` has an acknowledgement function

Comment: Also make sure you're providing enough arguments. I was playing around with a "getter" message that asks for data from the server, but on the client side, the getter didn't require sending actual text, because there's only one resource type. I had this: `socket.emit('get_messages, (messages: Message[]) => {`, but because I missed the second argument to `emit` (an empty string or some other filler data), the callback I supplied ended up being the data that was sent. I changed it to `socket.emit('get_messages', '', (messages: Message[]) => {`, and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone was having this problem, make sure that on the client, the emit has an acknowledgement function as the last parameter. If you write the server side code and restart the server again, it will give an error unless you have the client side page refreshed with the new code. Although I had written the code on both client and server, I kept getting the error on my server because I had not refreshed my client side page.